# Comparing two lists distinct value C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 2 lists say list1 and list2. Like

```
 List<int> list1 = {1,2,3};
 List<int> list2 = {3,4};
```

now I want my resultant list to be like

```
{1,2,3,4}
```

I have tried this

```
result= list1.Union(list2).ToList();
```

But it gives result like

```
{1,2,3,3,4}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], I cannot reproduce the behavior you're describing, what you're describing is the result of calling `.Concat`, not `.Union`, the behavior of `.Union` is exactly what you say you want. As such, you must post a [mcve] so that we can see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Possible you have lists of objects that do not implement `IComparable`

Comment: Your code returned `{1,2,3,4}` when I tested it. Is it really what you are doing?

Comment: Please bear in mind that if you're not *actually* comparing numbers, but your own types, you must override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in order for `.Union` to know how to compare your types. However, in the specific example you've posted, the code already does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple:

```
var result= list1.Union(list2).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: In the example given there should be no need for `.Distinct()` as the wanted behavior is exactly what `.Union` does.